# Telegram link to chat with text

Tags: telegram

Can I create telegram link with preset text just like Whatsapp did?

```
https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber?text=urlencodedtext
```

I couldn't find any of tips on the net.

I had tried this. It only open up telegram without text

```
tg://to=@username&text=presettext
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a URL that already contains a JS script inside that has `tg://` link.

```html
<a href="https://telegram.me/[username]">Text here</a>
```

Comment: Hello could you show your answer in code? There's no JS

Comment: @CaptainCrunch It's embedded Telegram's JS code not mine. Have you tried to open link with corresponding *username*?

Comment: I spend hours investigating. It's not possible. Period. You can only open a chat, but not add text automatically, like WhatsApp does. You can SHARE a URL + message, but this is not what op wants and also does not work without URL. This is the simple syntax to "chat"  https://t.me/+{Phone number}